# How to use a bool sentinel value to end a while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, boolean

I am having trouble using the bool value of END to stop running the loop ( code below). The rest of the program works, but I cannot seem to get the loop to stop when I type end. Any suggestions?

```
bool END = false;
while (!END)
{
    cout << "Please enter a song or END to terminate: ";
    getline(cin, track);

    results = binarySearch(tracks, numTracks, track);

    if (results == -1)
        cout << track << " is not on the set list.\n";
    else if (results != -1)
    {
        cout << track << " is on the set list.\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the loop to stop? END is always false.

Comment: `END` never changes inside the while loop

Comment: Do you mean you don't know how to check if the input is `"END"`? Because as others pointed out you never change the value of that variable so of course the loop never terminates.

Comment: Also note that `ALL_UPPER_CASE` will suggest to any programmer that the word is "a constant."   In code which actually works, you should use a `lower_case_name` and be sure that it is meaningful.

Comment: @MikeRobinson It will even suggest a preprocessor macro :) .

Answer (score 3):

```
if ( track == "END" )
     break;// or whatever you want to happen, e.g. END = true
```

you need to check against the users input.

Comment: ... and then, the loop can simply be `while(true) {` ... an immediate clue to any subsequent programmer that we only `break` out of this loop.

Answer (score 3):

In fact there is no need to use the while loop with a bool variable as the condition. You can rewrite your loop the following way

```
while ( true )
{
    cout << "Please enter a song or END to terminate: ";

    if ( !getline( cin, track ) || track == "END" ) break;

    results = binarySearch(tracks, numTracks, track);

    if ( results == -1 )
    {
        cout << track << " is not on the set list.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << track << " is on the set list.\n";
    }
}
```

Also pay attention to the else part of the if-else statement.